# Using select with Zend not returning results when value 1 is unquoted

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

Using PHP, Oracle and Zend 1.12. I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = 1;
```

normally it should return a single row, but somehow, after changing the Oracle server (which makes me believe this problem to be a database config issue), it returns nothing. Now, quoting the integer 1 as:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = '1';
```

It does return the row. By returning I'm saying that the result is shown to PHP.
If I run the same unquoted query in SQL Developer, for example, it returns the row correctly, which then makes me believe that it's not a database config issue, but Zend's.

But the same project is being used in other server and there is no trouble at all returning unquoted 1 values.

It only happens with 1. Anything grater or lesser than 1 works perfectly.

Suggestions for where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS to ",." fixed the issued as the manual states:

> If you have established a decimal character other than a period (.)
>   with the initialization parameter NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS, then you
>   must specify numeric literals with 'text' notation. In these cases,
>   Oracle automatically converts the text literal to a numeric value.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm

This behaviour is confirmed with Oracle 10.2g.